# Pandas split dataframe column for every character

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have multiple dataframe columns which look like this:

```
                         Day1
0    DDDDDDDDDDBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
1    DDDDDDDDDDBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
2    DDDDDDDDDDBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
3    DDDDDDDDDDBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
4    DDDDDDDDDDBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
```

What i want is that every character is seperated in a own column:

```
     012345678910111213....
0    DDDDDDDDDDBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
1    DDDDDDDDDDBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
2    DDDDDDDDDDBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
3    DDDDDDDDDDBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
4    DDDDDDDDDDBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
```

So that "Day 1-Column" is splitted in 48 Columns and every Column has one of the Value A/B/C/D

i tried with split, but that didnt work.

Comment: Post raw data, code to load your data into a df, in order for us to try to replicate your issue if our answers didn't work

Comment: It looks like you have trailing spaces, try `dataframe['Mo'] dataframe['Mo'].str.rstrip()` to remove any trailing spaces

Comment: Hi @EdChum i did this, but still the same result...

Comment: See my first comment, without data to reproduce this, this becomes a fishing expedition

Comment: ok i found the problem, i had trailing spaces. Thanks!!! @EdChum

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can call `apply` and for each row call `pd.Series` on the the `list` of the values:

```
In [16]:

df['Day1'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x)))
Out[16]:
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  ... 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
0  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D ...  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
1  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D ...  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
2  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D ...  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
3  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D ...  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
4  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D ...  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D

[5 rows x 48 columns]
```

It looks like you have trailing spaces, remove these using `str.rstrip`:

```
df['Day1'] = df['Day1'].str.rstrip()
```

then do the above.

Answer (score 6):

use [Series.str.extractall()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) method:

```
In [19]: df.Day1.str.extractall('(.)', flags=re.U)[0].unstack().rename_axis(None, 1)
Out[19]:
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  ... 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
0  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D ...  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
1  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D ...  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
2  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D ...  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
3  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D ...  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D
4  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D ...  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D  D

[5 rows x 48 columns]
```

Comment: Hey, i tried your way...i edited my question, there is anything wrong

Comment: @WarryS., do you have leading or trailing spaces? what is the output of `df.Day1.str.len()`?

Comment: its 48 vor every entry @MaxU, no between the values there are no spaces

Comment: @WarryS., i can't reproduce this behavior using provided sample data set :(

Comment: Thanks for your help @MaxU

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

`df['Day1'].str.split(pat ="\s*", expand = True)`

It will have empty 1st and last columns so you have to trim the dataframe using 
`df['Day1'].iloc[:,1:-1]`

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by @EdChum is effective for splitting strings, but it can be computationally expensive when dealing with large DataFrames. An alternative approach that offers improved performance is as follows:

```
df.Day1.str.split('', expand=True).iloc[:, 1:-1]
```

The use of `.iloc[:, 1:-1]` in this code is essential to remove the automatically added first and last columns that result from splitting a string with an empty delimiter ('').

---

To demonstrate the performance difference, consider the following benchmarking results:

```
python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['asdf' + str(x) for x in range(1000)], columns=['Day1'])

%%timeit
df.Day1.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x)))
# Result: 401 ms ± 2.13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
df.Day1.str.split(pat="\s*", expand=True).iloc[:, 1:-1]
# Result: 9.1 ms ± 83 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
df.Day1.str.split('', expand=True).iloc[:, 1:-1]
# Result: 8.59 ms ± 515 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

As you can observe, the `.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x))` method is nearly **50** times slower (401 ms vs. 8.59 ms) compared to the `.split()` method. The inefficiency arises from the conversion of each value into a Pandas Series, which can be particularly taxing on large datasets.

By utilizing the `.str.split()` approach, you can significantly enhance the performance of string splitting operations in your DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the answer from @ric-s, using `list` to separate the string is slightly faster when applying it outside of pandas:

```
In [1]: %timeit df['Day1'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x)))
1.08 ms ± 26.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [2]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([list(x) for x in df['Day1']])
718 µs ± 2.49 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Also, the following construction will create meaningful column names for the extracted features:

```
df[[f'Day1_{i}' for i in range(len(df['Day1'][0]))]] = pd.DataFrame([list(x) for x in df['Day1']])
```